# Save all attachments from mail

Tags: powershell, email, outlook

I have a script that is supposed to download all attachments from "Inbox" then move them to another folder named "Processed". I filter mails by subject. If exist then download all attachments and move the mails.
For example I have 5 mails with attachments (xls) the subject are named like:

```
BB_asd_green_dsa
AD_acv_blue_sf
FD__c_d_red_sa
CV_saas_white_sdsd
as_dc_asa_purple
```

When I start the script it saves 3 attachments, the mails with attachments are moved too. And then it stops.

Second start. It saves 1 attachment & moves 1 mail

And one last manual start script saves the last attachment and moves the mail.

For what reason doesn't the script save and move all attachments with their mails?

Here is the script:

```cs
$olFolderInbox = 6
$outlook = New-Object -Com Outlook.Application;

$ns = $outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI");
#$ns.Logon("Outlook")
#$ns.SendAndReceive($true)
#Start-Sleep -s 0
$inbox = $ns.GetDefaultFolder($olFolderInbox)
$messages = $inbox.Items
Write-Host $messages.Count
foreach ($message in $messages) {
    $msubject = $message.Subject
    $b = $msubject.Filename

    $filepath = "D:\Users\h.yordanov\Desktop\convertexltohtm\xls\"
    $message.Attachments | foreach{
        Write-Host $message.Filename
        $a = $_.Filename
        $msubject = $message.Subject
        $msubjectW = $msubject -replace '[^0-9]', ''
        $b = $msubjectW + ".xls"
        if ($msubject.Contains("green") -or $msubject.Contains("blue") -or $msubject.Contains("green") -or $msubject.Contains("white") -or $msubject.Contains("purple")) {
            $_.SaveAsFile((Join-Path $filepath $b))
        }
    }

    $MoveTarget = $inbox.Folders.Item("Processed")
    [void]$message.Move($MoveTarget)
}
```

I used this script to move the mails, but still not all 5 mails are moved at once:

```
    $Date = [DateTime]::Now.AddDays(-180)

$Last6Months =  $Date.tostring("MM/dd/yyyy")


$o = New-Object -comobject outlook.application
$n = $o.GetNamespace(“MAPI”)



$Account = $n.Folders | ? { $_.Name -eq 'h.yordanov@sample.com' };
$Inbox = $Account.Folders | ? { $_.Name -match 'Inbox' };
$TargetFolder = $Inbox.Folders.Item('Processed')


$Inbox.Items |
Where-Object -FilterScript {
    $_.senton -ge "$Last6Months"  
}  |
ForEach-Object -Process {
    [void]$psitem.Move($TargetFolder)
}
```

Btw i am using MS office Pro plus 2010 64-bit

Comment: I probably because you are moving the messages in the same loop as you are saving them. It's always dangerous to start changing things that you are looping over. Try to do one loop to find and save attachements and another to move.

Comment: You are right! I will try to fix it. Thanks! :)